# multiple pages app and vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use vuejs in a multiple pages app, say I have two pages:

/home and /account, I created two js files, home.js and account.js, home.js is included in home.html and account.js is included in account.html, this works quite well until I started to use webpack 4, webpack combines files into a single main.js, how to work with a single main.js in my use case? thanks

Comment: use something like [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/), then conform to doing it that way.. as a beginner it would be much simpler than trying to roll your own..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to have more than 1 Vue instance, for example, for home.js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#home'
    ...
```

and for account.js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#account'
    ...
```

and then just wrap the content of home.html with an id="home" and wrap the content of account.html with id="account"

Comment: this works, but since two Vue instances in the same js, when you load account.html, it has a warning:[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #home

Comment: this warning is harmless.  If you really want to get rid of it you can either provide a separate js file to each page or you can wrap the Vue instance with a condition so it only loads on the relevant page.

Comment: separate js file is the solution I finally used, webpack does have this multiple entry and output support, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this template as an example or starting point. The idea is the same no matter the backend technology.

https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template

You can create modules for pages which you want to enhance with Vue and import its bundle. There's also a medium article for more details :)